# Implicit differentiation rearrangement

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I had to calculate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the equation $2x^2 = \frac{x+y}{x-y}$

If I rearrange the equation like this: $2x^2(x-y) = x+y$

Now when I calculate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the above 2 equations, I get different answers
Why is this?
I checked my answers on Wolfram Alpha too

The answer for equation 1: $\frac{2x^3-4x^2y+2xy^2+y}{x}$

The answer for equation 2: $\frac{6x^2-4xy-1}{2x^2+1}$

Comment: The answers are probably strictly equivalent, you can rewrite one as the other. Checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers are the same.  If you replace $2x^2$ in the second solution in both places with $\frac{x+y}{x-y}$, you can turn one answer into the other.